# User does not have permission to query bigquery table

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I am using bigquery client to query data in a table:

```
query_job = self.bigquery_client.query("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE AGE={1}".format(table_name, 1))
        results = query_job.result()
```

This one works in another process under a service account (Using query1):

```
self.bigquery_client = bigquery.Client().from_service_account_json(self.access_key_path)
```

For another process where I query another table under another project, I can't query because I don't have permission to query the table.

I tried to use this code but I still get permission error (Using query2):

```
self.bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
# or self.bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project='PROJECT_ID')
```

How can I access both table without providing service account to my query(2)?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't really clear to me, are you authorizing access in both instances? When you say 'another process', is this in the same script? Can you share more complete code?

Comment: In order to be able to query to another project you must authenticate, I don't see how would you be able to query to another project before authenticating yourself. However, what I think that you want to achieve is to reuse the bigquery_client and use it to run the query to both of the projects. You can do so if the service account you are using has permissions in both projects.

Comment: be aware that shared project data has constrainst around regions.  you cant do US and EU for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client needs to be authenticated to the project you want to access.

If you need to query different tables in different projects your service account should have permissions in both projects. Another approach would be having one service account per project and creating one client per project (in your case, you would use different clients for different queries).

I suggest that you use the first approach because its not only more practical but it also avoid some problems. For example, if you want to JOIN both tables in a query, you'll need to have access to both at the same time which is not possible using separated service accounts.